# Upload document using nodeJs and GraphQL

Tags: node.js, flutter, graphql

how to create a server side for uploading document in nodeJs and GraphQL, I want to use it with a flutter client side

Comment: Try to check this link : https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter

Comment: thank you very much, I have checked it but I really want the server side with nodeJs and GraphQL